# Jest: Testing React state change in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-test-renderer

I am new at Jest and Enzyme, and am struggling to write a unit test to check if my component renders correctly when a certain state value exists.

Below is my code:

```
//Auth.js
export const Auth = ({ children }) => {
    const [authStatus, setAuthStatus] = useState('waiting')

    useEffect(()=>{
       const status = await getAuth()
       if (status) {
           setAuthStatus('Authed')
       }
       else{
           setAuthStatus('Unauthed')
       }
    },[])

    return (
       <>
          {authStatus === 'waiting' && <p>Loading...</p>}
          {authStatus === 'Authed' && <>{Children}</>
       </>
    )
}
```

In the above code, I wanted to test the Loading state when `authStatus` is default and I wanted to write a second test to test if the Children being passed in props are rendered when `authStatus` is Authed. I found a way to mock implement the state change, but that implementation is restricted to only one `useEffect`, as there may be multiple `useEffects` in the future, I do not want to go with this approach. Is there any better way to test this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

First mock `getAuth` and now You can have two separate test cases.

first test case-> your mocked getAuth function should return some defined value.This will help you in testing `{authStatus === 'Authed' && <>{Children}</>`. This will also cover the `if (status) { setAuthStatus('Authed') }` part.

second test case-> your mocked getAuth function should return some undefined value.This will cover your `else{ setAuthStatus('Unauthed') }` part

Answer (score 0):

first, you can't just use `await` keyword in `useEffect` callback, it should be an `async` function which would do that like this:

```
//Auth.js
export const Auth = ({ children }) => {
    const [authStatus, setAuthStatus] = useState('waiting')

    async function checkAuth(){
       const status = await getAuth()
       if (status) {
           setAuthStatus('Authed')
       }
       else{
           setAuthStatus('Unauthed')
       }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
       checkAuth();
    },[])

    return (
       <>
          {authStatus === 'waiting' && <p>Loading...</p>}
          {authStatus === 'Authed' && <>{Children}</>
       </>
    )
}
```

and then it's a best practice not to test implementation details like `state`.

usually, you want to mock `api calls` and imported `modules` like `getAuth` function.

so I think you should mock the `getAuth` function and then return your desired value in your mock so you can test if differnet state like `loading` will happen or not

Comment: Thanks for quicks response. This goes beyond the scope of my question, but can you please guide me on how to mock the `getAuth` function. I am new at writing Jest test cases and am struggling to mock the module (the module is imported from a third-party library)

Comment: Add all of the `Auth.js` code and your test file so we could see how you're doing it

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I have created a short version of my code on sandbox. Please have a look at it [there](https://codesandbox.io/live/r6un0u8).